# Avoid deleting files in my own directory - chmod command

Tags: chmod

I want to make sure that files I have in a specific directory cannot be deleted. Which `chmod` should I choose to be able to reads and use the files while still not be able to delete them? I would like to be able to reverse this `chmod` later in case I want to delete them another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to delete those files which can be write by only root user. There's two way to do it. Remove files as a root user. Or, make that file for public.

```
sudo rm -rf <directory name>
```

`chmod` is used for permission. There's three permission

1. Read
2. Write.
3. Execute.

If you want to enable all of them for public than run following command

```
sudo chmod 777 <directory name>
```

Read more about permisison [here](https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-command-in-linux/) and [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/437958/how-to-use-the-chmod-command-on-linux/)

If you want to disable permission for public and groups than, you should run following command

```
sudo chmod 700 <directory name>
```

First number used for `owner`(root user), second number used for `group` and third number used for `other access`(which I call public)

[image]

You can remember permission numbers [this way](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-733/).

- Read = 4
- Write = 2
- Execute = 1

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to delete files. I want to change permissions so that I cannot delete the files.

Comment: @user2300940 I have edited my answer.. If my answer helped you than pls mark as a correct answer...!

Comment: The mode bits on a file only affects the ability to read, write and execute the file. To forbid deleting files, you need to remove the write permission on *the containing directory*. This of course affects all files in the directory.

Comment: @JohanMyréen That's why I added number of those permissions...

Comment: @Istiak My point was that even doing a `chmod 000` on a file does not prevent deleting it. The mode bits on a file only affect reading, writing and execution. They have no effect on whether you can delete them or not.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent deleting individual files in a directory, you can make them immutable. Use the command `chattr +i filename` to make a file immutable. An immutable file cannot be modified, renamed or deleted. N.b. Not all filesystems support the immutable attribute, and only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Comment: 1) `chattr` availability depends on filesystem, so YMMV; 2) the poster would want it to add the attribute with `+i` instead of removing it with `-i` ; 3) one (usually) must be root to change the immutable attribute. Thus, I believe the desired command here would be `sudo chattr +i filename` .

Comment: @laubster You are correct. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Permission to create and delete files belongs to the directory they are in. Remove write permission from that directory and you will still be able to read/write files in that directory but you will neither be able to delete them nor create them.

```
mkdir try
touch try/one try/two
chmod u-w try         # Remove write (w) permission from the user (u)

# No more deletions or creations but files can still be edited

echo boo > try/one    # Ok
date > try/two        # Ok
echo baa > try/new    # Fails
rm try/two            # Fails

chmod u+w try         # Restore delete/create access

rm try/two            # Ok
```